# In c++, how do I wrap a Variadic function while changing the first parameter

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

How do I go about correctly wrapping a Variadic function when I need to change the first parameter's type?

For instance:

```
void original_function(char* format, ...)
{
  // Other Code Here
}


void wrapper(string format, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        original_function(format.c_str(), args);
        va_end(args);
}
```

For some reason, the need to convert it and cast it to a c string causes the other variables to not be read correctly. How do I correctly pass this information on while changing types of the first parameter?

Comment: What is `Message` and why aren't you using `format` in that location ?? Fix that first, then see below (thanks Raymond).

Comment: Use `vprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Thanks, that was a typo. Fixed now

Comment: @RaymondChen - That works great, thanks! Still somewhat interested in the overarching question as to if its possible vs just calling a different method. I guess perhaps I should read more into what these methods actually do. Tested your solution and it works great

Comment: @David *"if its possible"* - if *what* is possible ? You were calling a non-variadic function and passing a `va_arg` stack, expecting variadic results. This isn't a question of possible vs. not. It's not possible to use the *wrong* function to do what you were trying. Using the right function makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: It is not possible to generate a `...` from a `va_list`. Once a `...` has been captured into a `va_list`, then only thing you can do is consume it as a `va_list`, which means calling functions designed to accept `va_list`s.. However, since you appear to be using C++, you can use a variadic template.

Comment: Why is `wrapper`'s return type omitted? Why do you pass `string`s by value?